# iOS Corebluetooth: custom alert for background notification

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth

I'd thought you could override the iOS "The 'XXXX' accessory would like to open 'Application'" alerts with the following in my app delegate:

```
 - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:    (UILocalNotification *)notification
 {
if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationState] != UIApplicationStateBackground)
 {
     AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(1002);
 }
     AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(1002);

 NSString *appName = [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"CFBundleDisplayName"];
 UIAlertView *view = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:appName  message:[notification alertBody] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:[notification alertAction], nil];
 view.delegate = self;
 [view show];

  }
```

But this doesn't seem to be working for me.

(Just to clarify: I do have the boilerplate alerts working in the background, but I want to customize them).

Any pointers appreciated!

Comment: You're more likely to get a useful answer if you show us your code.

Comment: The override is in the app delegate, where it should be....the override is never getting called. I'll update the original question with the full code, but it's not creating a local notification that's the problem: it's overriding the default system generated alert.

Comment: Is this with Core Bluetooth or External Accessory Framework?

Comment: Hi @Paulw11 it's CoreBluetooth. As mentioned, I have no trouble generating system boilerplate alerts....just want to customize them!

Comment: Then how are you generating the local notification?  I haven't seen anything in-built to Core Bluetooth that displays those alerts.  Are you doing it in a CBCentral delegate method?

Comment: iOS is generating these alerts based on having "App communicates using CoreBluetooth" in "Required background modes" in the info.plist and then sending a [BLE] notification through a connected session.

Comment: Ok.  I've never seen that, but I haven't had a peripheral that sends notifications.  Are you trying to customise the app name or the alert body?

Comment: Did you specify the `CBConnectPeripheralOptionNotifyOnNotificationKey` when you connected to the peripheral?

Comment: @Paulw11 the alert body....preferably dynamically (i.e "you have an alert caused by X that shows Y").

I should be able to intercept incoming BLE callbacks, so I'm wondering if I can just register something like in Listing 2-3 on this page:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/IPhoneOSClientImp.html

Comment: Yes, you should get a call to your delegate notification method and you can issue the local notification from there.  Make sure that you haven't specified CBConnectPeripheralOptionNotifyOnNotificationKey when you connect so that you don't get the system generated alert

Comment: Hi @Paul11 I don't suppose you have a pointer or sample of code that you could share? :-/